# Retornar Status de compra no retorno automático de notificação PagSeguro

Tags: php

Alguém sabe como identificar os status de pagamento no retorno automático de notificações do pagseguro?
Por exemplo, se usuário efetuou o pagamento então, meu arquivo notificação.php recebe um post do pagseguro, mas nesse post não dá pra identificar  o status : PAGO por exemplo,( pra eu poder mandar um email de confirmação pra ele dizendo que a compra foi paga!)

Código php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['notificationType']) && $_POST['notificationType'] == 'transaction'){
    //Todo resto do código iremos inserir aqui.

    $email = 'loja@...';
    $token = '418C6...';

    $url = 'https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions/notifications/' . $_POST['notificationCode'] . '?email=' . $email . '&token=' . $token;

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $transaction= curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if($transaction == 'Unauthorized'){
        //Insira seu código avisando que o sistema está com problemas, sugiro enviar um e-mail avisando para alguém fazer a manutenção

        exit;//Mantenha essa linha
    }
    $transaction = simplexml_load_string($transaction);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta isso depois de `$transaction = simplexml_load_string($transaction);`:

```
    $transactionStatus = $transaction->status;
    if($transactionStatus == 1){
        $transactionStatus = 'Aguardando pagamento';
    } elseif($transactionStatus == 2){
        $transactionStatus = 'Em análise';
    } elseif($transactionStatus == 3){ // :)
        $transactionStatus = 'Paga';
    } elseif($transactionStatus == 4){ // :D
        $transactionStatus = 'Disponível';
    } elseif($transactionStatus == 5){
        $transactionStatus = 'Em disputa';
    } elseif($transactionStatus == 6){
        $transactionStatus = 'Devolvida';
    } elseif($transactionStatus == 7){
        $transactionStatus = 'Cancelada';
    }
```